# Web-app to convert RGB or hex colors to Delphi Tcolor values

Tags: gratis, web-apps, software-development, color, delphi

Please recommend a web-app that will convert RGB or hex colors to Delphi Tcolor values.

I've gone through over a dozen web-app color converters, and none I have found can convert to Delphi  Tcolor values.

This is an great example of what I'm looking for, except that Delphi Tcolor values are not one of its output formats:

- UIcolor.io: https://www.uicolor.io/

Note that I prefer the option to be able to enter either RGB or hex values for the input, but simply supporting one of those input methods is fine.

As a bonus, if it can also convert from Delphi Tcolor values to RGB or hex values, that would be most welcome.

Comment: Why not write a Delphi desktop application to do this conversion? It looks fairly simple to do.

Comment: @fpiette I haven't coded anything in Delphi in several years, so the ramp-up time to refamiliarize myself with it would be at least an hour or two.

Comment: What is *an hour or two* given the fact you asked your question 6 months ago :-) Do you got any solution since then?

Comment: @fpiette No solution since then, but I'm looking for a tool to save me 5 minutes a couple times each year, not spend 1-2 hours.

Comment: Delphi TColor value is in BGR. So for converting RGB hex value to TColor you only need to swap R and B. You can use uicolor.io and then for picked value #1273DE equivalent Delphi TColor would be $DE7312.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Thank you for your comment.  IIRC, when represented as decimal values (which some applications require for their configuration files), TColor values are often negative.  Is there a good way to convert the hex TColor value to decimal and have it become negative when necessary?  (Doing 3 things at once right now, so if you need more details, please just let me know.)

Comment: Color with negative value is actually Windows system color. You can get BGR value from that with GetSysColor(color and $000000FF) and actual BGR value depends on current Windows theme. See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsyscolor Delphi adds $FF000000 to the system color constant to distinguish it from regular BGR values. Going back from BGR (or RGB) to system color is a bit tricky and it requires mapping between system color constants and their BGR values and then finding whether BGR value you have matches any of the system colors.

Comment: BTW, I am not sure whether posting Delphi code that would do the conversions is acceptable here, since you were asking about web application.